# android adapter from async task

Tags: android, android-asynctask, adapter

In one of my app, I need to use `AsyncTask.` I need to get an image URL from an HTTP site. I have done this in the `doInBackground` method. I am getting the URL of that image as a string.

```
publishProgress(thumb);//thumb is string
```

then in

```
        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {

            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
            sample = new ArrayList<String>();

            System.out.println("this is on progress..."+values[0]);
            sample.add(values[0]);

            GridviewAdapter_old go=new GridviewAdapter_old(getActivity(), sample);

            gv.setAdapter(go);
            //          gv.setAdapter(ga);
        }
```

---

```
public class GridviewAdapter_old extends BaseAdapter

{

    private ArrayList<String> listCountry;

    private Activity activity;

    public GridviewAdapter_old(Activity activity, ArrayList<String> listCountry) {
        super();

        // this.listCountry = listCountry;
        this.listCountry = new ArrayList<String>();
        this.listCountry = listCountry;
        // this.listFlag = listFlag;
        this.activity = activity;
        System.out.println("this is contry name " + this.listCountry);
        // System.out.println("this is img  name  " + this.listFlag);
        // System.out.println();

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("len " + listCountry.size());
        // return listCountry.size();
        return listCountry.size();
    }

    @Override
    public String getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return listCountry.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder {
        public ImageView imgViewFlag;
        // public TextView txtViewTitle;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ViewHolder view;
        LayoutInflater inflator = activity.getLayoutInflater();

        if (convertView == null) {
            view = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.test, null);

            view.imgViewFlag = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.grid_item_image);

            // view.imgViewFlag.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.view_default);
            convertView.setTag(view);

        }

        else {

            view = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        try {
            URL myUrl = new URL(listCountry.get(0));
            InputStream inputStream = (InputStream) myUrl.getContent();
            Drawable drawable = Drawable.createFromStream(inputStream, null);
            view.imgViewFlag.setImageDrawable(drawable);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());

        }
        /*
         * Bitmap imageBitmap = null; //System.gc(); try { URL imageURL = new
         * URL(listCountry.get(0));
         * System.out.println("this is in last portion..."
         * +listCountry.get(position)); imageBitmap =
         * BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageURL.openStream());
         * view.imgViewFlag.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap); //
         * view.txtViewTitle.setText(listCountry.get(position)); //
         * view.imgViewFlag.setImageResource(listFlag.get(position));
         * 
         * } catch (Exception e) { System.out.println("this is error " +
         * e.getMessage()); }
         */

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

The problem is:

- I am not getting an image from the URL (that is getting from thumb (`publishProgress(thumb);`)
- I am not getting the multiple images.

Answer (score 1):

you are only getting one in your list because every time you call `onProgressUpdate` you create a new list.

You dont want to use onProgressUpdate to populate your list, that would be an insane amount of overhead. Instead you want to create your list inside your doInBackground then pass that list to your `onPostExecute` then put the new list to the adapter and call `notifyDatasetChanged` on the adapter to refresh the list.

in short, create the adapter (class wide variable), create an ArrayList (class wide variable) and everytime a change is made the the list all you have to do is call `notifyDatasetCHanged` on the adapter

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String();
ArrayAdapter adapter;

public class AsyncTask.....

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params){
    ...
    list.add(stuff);
}

@Override
protected Void onPostExecute(Void params){
    adapter.notifyDatasetChanged();
}
```